# Remove quantities from several rows with a certain order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write down a update/delete query that allows me to ask to remove x quantities and the query will delete/update the rows while it has values.

For example the table bellow (Its a simplified version from mine, just to get the idea) I am some other validations that I want to make but this is only my main question.

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ Rowid ║ qtd ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 1     ║ 2   ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 2     ║ 1   ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 3     ║ 3   ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 4     ║ 4   ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 5     ║ 3   ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 6     ║ 5   ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

Imagine I write a query to delete 9 quantities here.

the end result should be something like.

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ Rowid ║ qtd ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 1     ║ 2   ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 2     ║ 1   ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 3     ║ 3   ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
║ 4     ║ 3*  ║
╠═══════╬═════╣
╠═══════╬═════╣
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

What happened here:

- 5 Quantities were removed from row 6, because the row reached 0 it has been deleted.
- 3 Quantities were removed from row 5, because the row reached 0 it has been deleted.
- 1 Quantity was removed from row 4, the new value has been updated from 4 to 3.

I wanted to see if I could have some viable option directly in sql. to avoid doing some ugly hardcoding using some other options.

And by having a clean sql Option I could save this a learn more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cumulative sum and some logic:

```
select rowid,
       (case when running_qtd < 5 then 0
             when running_qtd - qtd < 5 then running_qtd - qtd
             else qtd
        end) as amount_left
from (select t.*, sum(qtd) over (order by rowid desc) as running_qtd
      from t
     ) t;
```

This includes all rows and puts the remaining `qtd` in the column.

Comment: There's no delete or update in here. I still have no clue how to make sql choose witch option to use..

Comment: @AlexandreCalvario . . . Don't delete the rows.  Just set `qtd` to `0`.